# iP appearance in two or more nodes in sticky load balancing

Tags: session, logging, load-balancing

Currently, there is a server configured with sticky load balancing.

A specific user (IP) is active in Node 4, but suddenly it is also confirmed in Node 1 at the same time.

Is there a log to see the contents other than the application log?

As far as I know, in case of sticky load balancing, you have to keep using Node4 until the session is cut off.

log searching and log anl